# Convert empty inputs from HTML form to None in Flask to store them as NULL in PostgreSQL

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy

I have an HTML form, that I handle the request in a Flask app. If some of the inputs are empty strings, I want to transform them into `None` values, so what I can store them as `NULLs` in a PostgreSQL DB through SQLAlchamy.

So far the only things that works is the following:

```
# convert empty strings to None
if parts == "":
    parts = None
if car_model == "":
    car_model = None
if item_count == "":
    item_count = None

# save to db
sale = Sales(date=date, parts=parts, car_model=car_model,
             item_count=item_count, value=value)
```

Is there any more elegant way to do this? I tried some things but nothing was successful.

I read that you can specify the `None` value, when getting the input from the form:

```
parts = request.form.get('parts', None)
```

I also tried creating an array and then loop over it. The problem is that the original variables don't change, the variables in the set are.

```
s = [parts, car_model, item_count)
for i, item in enumerate(s):
    if item == "":
        s[i] = None
```

If I had much more variables, creating an if statement for each one would be inefficient. Is there any more efficient, more pythonic way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
parts = request.form.get('Parts') or None
```

or

```
parts = request.form['Parts'] or None
```

Which will still return a 400 if the 'Parts' was never in the form in the first place.

if the `Parts` in the form is an empty string, it will ensure that the `parts` variable becomes `None`.

Console example:

```
>>> print('' or None)
None

>>> print('hello' or None)
hello
```

Comment: The first solution can be like this right? `parts = request.form.get('Parts') or None`. There is no need for having `None` inside the get method.

Comment: Yes, that would be even cleaner than the current solution. I'll update it.